# Recursive function collects lists, but they are all the same

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursive-backtracking

So the output i want should be something like this:

```
[[9],[9,8],[9,8,7]...[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]]
```

and this is the code that i am using:

```
a=[]
b=[]
i=0
def recur(i):
    i+=1
    if i<10:
        x=recur(i)
    else:
        return a
    b.append(i)
    a.append(b)
    return x
x=recur(i)
```

Please tell me what is wrong in this code that i am getting such a output like this:

```
[[9,8,7,...,1],[9,8,7,..1]....]
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because during the whole execution process there are only two lists `a` and `b`. There is no code that creates a third, fourth or more lists. It just mutates lists `a` and `b`.

For `a` that is fine, because that is the *single* list you will return to the caller (no matter that it gets the name `x` along the way, but that is just a synonym for `a`).

But for `b` it is problematic, because it gets appended to `a` *repeatedly*. Every time your code appends a value to it, this will be visible via `a[0]`, via `a[1]`, ...etc, since all these are synonyms for the list `b`.

To fix this, make a *new* list each time you want to append to `a`. Also avoid using global variables:

```
def recur(i):
    i += 1
    if i >= 9:
        return [[i]]
    
    a = recur(i)
    # Create a new(!) list based on the last one that was collected
    b = a[-1] + [i]
    a.append(b)
    return a


x=recur(0)
```

Now `x` will be:

```
[[9], [9, 8], [9, 8, 7], [9, 8, 7, 6], [9, 8, 7, 6, 5], [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3], [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2], [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: but y is the value that is already appended to the list a changing?

Comment: There is no rule that says that something that is appended to a list cannot change. Just realise that there is only **one** `b` list in your code, not more. So whatever happens to `b` can be seen at all places where you have put a reference to it, like when the references in list `a` are all references to this same `b` list.